# TensorFlow: How to skip broken data

Tags: tensorflow

I am playing with TensorFlow 1.0. My input data are bulk of jpeg images. Some of them are broken for different reasons, and I just want to skip them at input.

Image loading part of the Graph is the following:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once(filename_list), capacity=1000, num_epochs=1)
whole_file_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, image_binary = whole_file_reader.read(filename_queue)
image_tensor = tf.cast(tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_binary), tf.float32)
```

Model running part as usual:

```
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_local)
        sess.run(init_all)

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

        try:
                while not coord.should_stop() and not sv.should_stop():
                        sess.run(accumulator)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
                #
        except Exception as e:
                # Report exceptions to the coordinator.
                coord.request_stop(e)
        finally:
                coord.request_stop()

        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

When running this code I see the following, and I could not figure out how to catch this exception correctly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid JPEG data, size 0
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=0, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ReaderReadV2:1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculate_mean.py", line 67, in <module>
    coord.join(threads)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 973, in managed_session
    self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 801, in stop
    stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 386, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 234, in _run
    sess.run(enqueue_op)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid JPEG data, size 0
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=0, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ReaderReadV2:1)]]

Caused by op 'DecodeJpeg', defined at:
  File "calculate_mean.py", line 19, in <module>
    image_tensor = tf.cast(tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_binary), tf.float32)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_image_ops.py", line 345, in decode_jpeg
    dct_method=dct_method, name=name)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2395, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/matwey/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Invalid JPEG data, size 0
         [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=0, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ReaderReadV2:1)]]
```

Unfortunately, an answer given in
[Skipping nonexistent or corrupt files in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690603/skipping-nonexistent-or-corrupt-files-in-tensorflow)
doesn't work for me. It seems that in my case an exception is raised by `coord.join(threads)` which is too late.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late response. The answer may be contained in your error message:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid JPEG data, size 0
>            [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=0, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

For whatever reason a JPEG file may be corrupted. However, you've used the default settings for `tf.image_decode_jpeg` which requires perfect decoding. Instead you may want to allow some error by setting parameters `try_recover_truncated = True` and `acceptable_fraction=0.5` (or whatever). See [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_jpeg) for more.